# Using MousePosition on the entire screen - Screencast with Linux

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, eventhandler, dynamic

In order to record animations more easily while using *Mathematica* on *Linux*, I would need to know how to get the position of three clicks.

The following picture (main part generated by `Panel[Graphics@Disk[], ImageSize -> 200]`) shows the idea:

[image]

`Dynamic@MousePositon[]` shows the coordinates of the mouse within the *Mathematica* window but how to save the position of the clicks? (knowing that `EventHandler` works only in the Output cell).

Then the idea is to get `posi={xi,yi}` and to record the screen (using [byzanz](https://github.com/GNOME/byzanz)) automatically:

```
time = 5; delay = 2; path = "test";
toGIF = ToString@StringForm[
  "byzanz-record --duration=`` --x=`` --y=`` --width=`` --height=`` --delay=``",
  time, First@pos1, Last@pos1, Subtract[#, #2] & @@ (First /@ {pos2, pos1}),
  Subtract[#, #2] & @@ (Last /@ {pos3, pos2}), delay] <> path <> ".gif"
```

Then `Run@toGIF` would produce the GIF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pos = {};
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {
   "MouseClicked" :> If[CurrentValue["AltKey"], 
                        AppendTo[pos, MousePosition[]]], 
    PassEventsDown -> True}]


 Dynamic@MousePosition[]
 Dynamic@pos
```

So, while pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd> you can click to store your positions.

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide a full answer (and thanks [Kuba's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46745/1356)) in case someone wants to screencast while using *Mathematica* and [*byzanz* (Gnome only)](https://askubuntu.com/a/123515):

```
recordGif::Usage = "Record Mathematica animations; Syntax: recordGif[time,delay]";
recordGif[time_, delay_] :=

  DynamicModule[{pathToGif, pathToSh, toGIF, posGIF},
  Panel@Column[{
    Button["Run", Print["Starting in " <> ToString@delay <> " seconds for " <> ToString@time <> " seconds."];
      Run@toGIF[posGIF, pathToGif]],
    Button["Export to a shell script",
      {Export[pathToSh, toGIF[posGIF, pathToGif], "Lines"];
       Run["chmod +x " <> pathToSh];
       Print["Exported to " <> pathToSh];}],
    Dynamic@posGIF}, ItemSize -> 22],
  Initialization :>
    (
    posGIF = {};
    pathToGif = "~/mmagif.gif"; pathToSh = "~/mmash";
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions :>
      {"MouseClicked" :> If[CurrentValue["ControlKey"], 
       AppendTo[posGIF, MousePosition[]]], PassEventsDown -> True}];
    toGIF[posGIF_, path_] := (ToString@StringForm[
      "byzanz-record --duration=`` --x=`` --y=`` --width=`` --height=`` --delay=`` ", 
      time, First@posGIF[[1]], Last@posGIF[[1]], 
      Abs@Subtract[#, #2] & @@ (First /@ {posGIF[[2]], 
          posGIF[[1]]}), 

      Abs@Subtract[#, #2] & @@ (Last /@ {posGIF[[3]], 
          posGIF[[2]]}), delay] <> path <> " &");
)]
```

Evaluating `recordGif[5,5]` as follow shows:

[image]

By clicking while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the 3 points shown [in the question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryLAL.png) and by clicking on the `Run` button you get:

[image]

and by clicking on the button `Export to a shell script` you get in `mmash`:

> byzanz-record --duration=5 --x=253 --y=220 --width=493 --height=324 --delay=5 ~/test.gif &

which you can simply run a terminal: `./mmash`.

Comment: +1 there is somewhere on meta.mathematica a topic about capturing methods. you may want to link this answer to it :)

Comment: I will do [that](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/how-to-make-animated-screen-captures/1059#1059) tomorrow :) If you have any idea how to make the variable `posGIF` local and not global please feel free to tell me :D I lost patience with that thing :P

Comment: Move those 3 first lines `posGIF = {}; pathToGif =...;   SetOptions[...` at the beginning of `Initialization`. Why? `posGIF` appears in body wrapped with `Dynamic`, those symbols are forcing definitions from `Initialization` to evaluate before the rest.

Comment: Thanks :) That seems quite simple now :)